# How to align text and images on one line and position those to the left and/or right?

Tags: html, css, image, text, alignment

I have the following CSS and HTML code:

```
div.container { height: 40px; }
div.container .title {}
div.container .link_buttons {}


<div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="title">
      <img width="16" height="16" src="/favicon.ico" alt="Text">

      <a href="http://www.test.com">Test website</a>
    </div>

    <div class="link_buttons">
      <a target="_blank" href="http://www.test.com">
        <img src="transparent.gif" class="background_image" alt="Text">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- The same structure as the above but with different data. -->
  <div class="container">...</div>
  <div class="container">...</div>
</div>
```

I would like to align on the same line all the content present in each `div.container` and inside each `div.container` to make the `div.title` content to be positioned on the left and the `div.link_buttons` content to be positioned on the right. Made this, I would like to *vertical align* `div.title` and `div.link_buttons` in the *middle* of `div.container`.

How can I style the CSS the proper way? Or, have I to rethink and change the whole HTML code so to simplify things? If so, what I can make in order to have the same result?

---

Note: I tried to use float, but I am in trouble mostly because then I can not vertical align the `div.title` and `div.link_buttons` inside the `div.container` (as you can see in the above code, it has `height: 40px;`).

Comment: I also come up to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7273338/how-to-vertically-align-an-image-inside-div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
div.container { height: 40px; line-height:40px;}
div.container .title {float:left;}
div.container .link_buttons {float:right}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WH4eK/

Answer (score 0):

```
.title { float: left } /* Float them */
.link_buttons { float: right }
.container:after { /* And clear the float */
    content: '';
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: In my tests I got almost your same results. The problem is that I cannot vertical align `div.title` and `div.link_buttons` inside the `div.container` (note: it has `height: 40px;`). I would like to *vertical align* those in the middle of the container.