# Border bottom property gives the h1 tag 100% border width

Tags: css

i have taken this `h1` and i have given it a class and applied border bottom to it so that i can give a nice underline effect.
I can use `text-decoration` property but giving  bold underline effect gives me the ability to have width of underline line.
When i give `h1` an underline, the border goes to 100% full width of the container.
please tell me how to fix it.
thanks.

Comment: First complete the question by providing some piece of code..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `display: inline` the reason why the H1 is showing the border all the way across is because it is a displaying block by default. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Because `h1` is a block level element and by default this element take a 100% width. so make it a inline element.

here is the CSS to build the `h1` as a inline element.

```
h1{border-bottom:1px solid red;display:inline-block;}
```

here is the HTML

```
<h1>My First Heading</h1>
```

Here is a Demo.. http://jsbin.com/voyuluyo/1/edit

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

---

```
<h1 class="headings"> hi this is SO </h1>

<h1 class="headings1"> hi this is SO </h1>
```

**CSS**

---

```
.headings
{
    border-bottom:10px solid black;
    
}

.headings1
{
    display:inline-block;
    border-bottom:10px solid red;
}
```

**Fiddle**

---

## [Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HHn8r/4/)

**Output:**

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As RaySinlao said, `display:block` will make it expand all the way. If you want to make the next element go to the next line, `display:inline` won't work. Use `display:table`. Table will shrink-wrap (to fit contents) or expand (to fix [weird bugs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21719194/expanding-parent-div-to-child-size-when-larger-than-page-width/21719241#21719241)) or [clearfix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21636666/how-to-align-text-and-images-on-one-line-and-position-those-to-the-left-and-or-r/21636780#21636780). Come to think of it, table does a lot of stuff.